# Send keyboard-commands to PC from Android via USB or network (without modifying the Kernel)

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard-events

I'm looking for a way to send various keyboard-commands from my Android-Tablet to my Windows 10 system. I already did some research here, but I am looking for a possibility to achieve this **without modifying the Kernel**. This should work either via USB or via network.
Is there a way to write this in a pure Kotlin-based app?

Comment: From my knowledge It can't be done without editing the kernel, but I might be wrong, but a thing to remeber like one of my lecturers said, "To make Popcorn you gotta use the kernels"- cheesy and irrelevant but still its something to remeber to not be scared of editng the kernel etc