# Xamarin android emulate usb PC Keyboard

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, keyboard

I want to code with Xamarin for android mobile an application that could be connected to a comptuer with usb cable and emulate a usb PC Keyboard.
When we'll click on a button on the application, I want the application send a Keyboard key code like if a normal keyboard was connected.

I don't succeed to find the correct way to persuade the comptuer this is a keyboard neither receive any key code..

Have you any ideas how to do that?

Comment: I doubt this is possible, and if it is it is most likely very difficult

Comment: According to this case :[Send keyboard-commands to PC from Android via USB or network (without modifying the Kernel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62637963/send-keyboard-commands-to-pc-from-android-via-usb-or-network-without-modifying), you may need to modify the Kernel.